# golang downloaded packages outside of src folder

Tags: go

When i install package like this:

```
go get github.com/go-zoo/bone
```

it's create a folder in src folder like this:

```
src/github.com/go-zoo/bone
```

I want to keep src folder only for my own code.

Comment: The `src/` directory in GOPATH is where all go packages are found. That's how the `go` tool works. You can add multiple entries to GOPATH if you want, but that will only complicate your environment for little benefit. [How To Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution of my problem, is to create a vendor folder in your project directory,like so:

```
src:
  - vendor:
    - packages...
```

its like an npm or any package manager.

there also tools like:
[govend](https://github.com/govend/govend) and trash.